# Check that two strings are equal in freemarker, one string contains & symbol

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm using *freemarker* to check if two Strings are equal or not.

```
<#if vm == 'O&M VMs'>    
   <td width="189" rowspan="9"><p align="center">${vm}</p></td>
</#if>
```

I'm sure the `${vm}` is `'O&M VMs'`, but it doesn't enter the *if block*. If there is no `&` symbol, the string comparison works, but I need to keep the `&`. I tried to change it to `&amp;` like `<#if vm == 'O&amp;M VMs'>`, still not working. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing special in a `&` in a string literal for FreeMarker. I suspect some other tool distorts the template before FreeMarker gets it. (You can try it on http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/; that's how it should work.) Or, maybe it's the value of `vm` that the template gets pre-escaped or something. What if you compare to `"O\aamp;M VMs"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<#if vm == 'O\aM VMs'>...` - `\a` is an escape sequence for ampersand (see http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_string).

Comment: Thanks, Jozef, I tried the `<#if vm == 'O\aM VMs'>` as well, still not working

Comment: Strange. I've just tested it locally, and if my variable contains `'Foo & bar'`, then both `<#if myVar == 'Foo & bar'>` and `<#if myVar == 'Foo \a bar'>` work. Which version of Freemarker do you use (my is 2.3.21)? And is it pure Freemarker (as a servlet), or anyhing more (Spring, Liferay, ...)?

Comment: My version of Freemarker is 2.3.18, I'm using Freemarker + Flying-saucer + Itext to generate PDF file, everything works fine, the problems comes only there is a & in the String.

Comment: It is strange, I changed the version to 2.3.21, and print the variable `<h1>${vm}</h1>`  it is O&M VMs, and I tried `<#if vm == 'O\aM VMs'>` and `<#if vm == 'O$amp;M VMs'>`, they don't work. only I changed the `${vm}` to `O and M VMs`, and use `<#if vm == 'O and M VMs'>`, it works, but I'd better keep &